# what is the difference between [ Buffer.from(tag_name, "hex") ] and [ Buffer.from(tag_name).toString("hex") ] in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

what is the difference between [  Buffer.from(tag_name, "hex")  ] and [ Buffer.from(tag_name).toString("hex") ] in NodeJs

```
const { Buffer } = require("buffer");

var tag_name = "79";

tag_s = Buffer.from(tag_name).toString("hex");      // result :     tag_s = 3739
tag_ss = Buffer.from(tag_name, "hex");              // result :     tag_ss = y


console.log(`tag_s = ${tag_s}`);
console.log(`tag_ss = ${tag_ss}`);
```

Comment: One is converting the input string from hex, the other is converting to hex.

Comment: but both the inputs are string "79" , i think the result shouldn't be different... !